# NameError: name 'command' is not defined

Tags: python

I want to send MSSQL data to telegram bot via python. This is what I have written thus far:

```
import time
import random
import datetime
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop

import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-OM8N0ER\SQLEXPRESS01;'
                      'Database=SmartHome;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

print ('Command received: %s') % command


if command == '/about':
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Hi, I\'m netrapsystembot')
elif command == '/random':
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, random.randint(0,9))
elif command == '/time':
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(datetime.datetime.now()))

elif command == '/sessions':
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SmartHome.dbo.SensorData')
    for result in cursor.fetchall():
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, result [0])

bot = telepot.Bot('803777982:AAEmtO98wjYcqoFqWXOSuYTeg6HFG6xUnwk')
MessageLoop(bot,handle).run_as_thread()
print ('Bot ready!')

while 1:
   time.sleep(10)
```

But I am currently receiving this error message at this line:

```
print ('Command received: %s') % command
```

> NameError: name 'command' is not defined

Comment: Please post your code here directly. Do not link to images of code.

Comment: Hai Sir, i have trouble in paste the code in here, i have attach a link to my code Sir

Comment: Your main issue is that you are calling the command variable before using the function that actually defines what command does. So it doesn't exist but you are trying to use it thus the error.

Comment: how i can fix it Sir? Tq

@EdekiOkoh

Comment: Use the handle function and return command and chat_id before this line :print ('Command received: %s') % command

Comment: I think that this may just be a spacing problem. What do u want the handle function to do?

Comment: Yes Sir i think the spacing problem,but im not sure where is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to debug without more information, but I think the issue is the spacing of your function handle. You defined command inside of the function handle but are trying to access it without returning the variable handle or calling it until the end. This makes me believe that you have a spacing issue with your function entirely. Now your function handle will actually send a message after it is called, instead of just initializing two variables and not using them.

```
import time
import random
import datetime
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop

import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DESKTOP-OM8N0ER\SQLEXPRESS01;'
                      'Database=SmartHome;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    print ('Command received: %s') % command


    if command == '/about':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Hi, I\'m netrapsystembot')
    elif command == '/random':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, random.randint(0,9))
    elif command == '/time':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(datetime.datetime.now()))

    elif command == '/sessions':
         cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM SmartHome.dbo.SensorData')
         for result in cursor.fetchall():
             bot.sendMessage(chat_id, result [0])

bot = telepot.Bot('803777982:AAEmtO98wjYcqoFqWXOSuYTeg6HFG6xUnwk')
MessageLoop(bot,handle).run_as_thread()
print ('Bot ready!')

while 1:
   time.sleep(10)
```

However you are not passing a message into handle anywhere so the function will not execute in this current state.